# Is stellar luminosity vs redshift calculated incorrectly?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

In [this paper](http://www.ptep-online.com/2013/PP-34-11.PDF) the author, T.X. Zhang, asserts that the luminosity of distant supernovae normally is calculated incorrectly.  His point (if I understand his paper) is that "luminosity" should mean energy emitted per unit time; and that therefore the calculation of luminosity should take time dilation into account - but does not.

This is outside my field, but is intriguing. Is he right?  Does the standard calculation of luminosity overlook time dilation that would accompany Doppler shift?

Comment: I notice that his abstract ends with the line "This result indicates that our universe has not accelerated and does not need dark energy at all.", but barely touches on the fact that Type Ia supernovae observations are *not* the only signs we have of dark energy - observations of CMB fluctuations, baryon acoustic oscillations, large-scale cosmic structure, etc. There's maybe one paragraph or so later on that mentions that.

Comment: Noted, thanks!  However, it's specifically the luminosity-vs-redshift calculations I'm curious about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The luminosity distance is a *defined* quantity, it is not a quantity that is derived in any way. It is defined as $\sqrt{L/4\pi f}$, where $L$ is the *intrinsic* luminosity of a source (a standard candle in this case) and $f$ is the measured flux of that object.

Zhang's paper appears to change the *definition* of luminosity distance.

Progress in Physics is not a well-respected journal; that in itself is not a reason to dismiss the work, but it is a reason to check it very carefully.

Comment: Thanks for introducing "luminosity distance".  Searching for that yielded this article [http://burro.case.edu/Academics/Astr222/Cosmo/Observing/observing.shtml], which makes it clear that the time dilation effect -- at least in a flat universe-- is indeed accounted for in the standard calculation.

Comment: @S.McGrew The link is broken; but surely there is nothing to account for. $L$ is the *intrinsic* luminosity and $f$ is what you *measure*. Sure, any *prediction* of how $D_L$ depends on redshift then depends on cosmological parameters and does indeed include time dilation and other effects.